# Adding property to object with node.js

Tags: node.js

Im trying to add a property to a JSON object in NODE.

Im doing as I do with angular:

```
 APIresponse.membershipData.dependents[i].age=age;
```

But it is not working, its just not adding the property.

Is the syntax different in Node?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
APIresponse.membershipData.dependents[i]["age"]=age;
```